# Defining a selector in angular component breaks my layout

Tags: angular

I've created a company profile component that stands alone as it's own page. But I need to use it elsewhere in my app so I defined the selector like so:

```
selector: 'company-profile'
```

I've got a permanent navbar on the left and a permanent toolbar on the top that are separate components and in the `app.component.html` so all of the pages should render their content below the `toolbar` and to the right of the `navbar`.

However, when I created the selector in the `@Component`, the page disregarded the `toolbar` and `navbar` and expanded underneath them. When I comment out the selector, everything works normally. And when I use `<company-profile></company-profile>` elsewhere in the app it works perfectly as well.

***app.component.html***

```
<div fxLayout="row">
  <tn-nav style="z-index:5;"></tn-nav>
  <div fxFlex fxLayout="column">
    <tn-toolbar></tn-toolbar>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

***company-profile.component.ts***

```
@Component({
  selector: 'company-profile',
  templateUrl: '../html/company-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../styles/company-profile.component.scss',
      '../../../shared/styles/buttons.shared.scss'],
})
```

***In another component***

```
<div fxFlex="75">
  <company-profile></company-profile>
</div>
```

There are no errors in the console either. What seems to be the issue?

Comment: can you please share your code ? and do you have any error in console ?

Comment: Just FYI, it's a **bad idea to put shared HTML files in a dedicated folder**. Consider following the Angular Style Guide by placing your component files in the same folder: https://angular.io/guide/styleguide

Comment: Did you declare the other component in your app's module?

Comment: try to use Angular Cli i see your paths are relative.

Comment: @Edric thanks. I'll read over the style guide better and change the style. But yes. The other component is in my app module. It works everywhere else in the app when I declare the selector except on the company profile page where it's offset because it is extending under the toolbar and navbar.